# posix can't get file into type file

Tags: applescript

I have a code like this:

```
      set thisFolder to choose folder with prompt "Please select an output folder:"
do shell script " cd " & destinationFolder & ";  ls " & destinationFolder & space & ">" & space & "accountslist.rtf"
        set accountslist to quoted form of (POSIX path of (thisFolder as text) & "accountslist.rtf")
    set theaccounts to paragraphs of (read accountslist)
    set theaccount to choose from list theaccounts with prompt "Select Account You Want To Export"
```

When a run, it says can't make /file location/ into file type, can anyone tell me the problem?

What I try to achieve is to export all folders inside a folder to a text file & then show it as a list in applescript, then I need the chosen save as a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because you need `quoted form of` only in `do shell script` lines to escape paths

Replace

```
set accountslist to quoted form of (POSIX path of (thisFolder as text) & "accountslist.rtf")
```

with

```
set accountslist to POSIX path of thisFolder & "accountslist.rtf"
```

Note:

Be aware that the `ls` command returns `.txt` not `.rtf`

Comment: is there any way to only return folder names but not files?

Comment: Get the names with System Events or Finder

Answer (score 0):

The complete code is like this:

```
  set accountslist to POSIX path of thisFolder & "accountslist.txt"
set theaccounts to paragraphs of (read accountslist)
set theaccount to choose from list theaccounts with prompt "Select Account You Want To Export"
```